# How to get platform IDs from boost?

Tags: c++, boost, operating-system

How can we know which operating system the code is running?

e.g.
How to know the operating system like Unix-Linux, Solaris, HP Unix, Windows, Mac etc?

How can we determine operating system in C++ code with boost?
I want to test with Boost v1.41 onwards.

Comment: One knows on which family of operating system code will run at compile time. Querying particular OS version could be done using platform-specific method.

Comment: I want to check at runtime. Some kind of class method which gives OS info.

Comment: You could use QSysInfo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063110/get-the-current-operating-system-during-runtime-in-c

Comment: Boost offers only compile time recognition.

Comment: If you don't know if you are compiling for Mac or Windows, you will compile it all wrong and the program will never start. So it *must* be known long before you try to run the program.

Comment: @MichałFita because run time recognition is useless. It must be known at compile time. You can only check the OS version at run time. But the code must be targeted for that specific OS when compiling

Answer (score 4):

Code must be compiled to the specific platform you're targeting so you **must** know the platform at *compile time*. For example Linux binaries can't be run on BSD, Solaris, AIX... so checking the OS at runtime makes no sense and is useless

That means the OS needs to be checked via preprocessor directives and **not** in a C statement. There's [`Boost.Predef`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/predef/doc/index.html) which contains various predefined macros for determining the platform

> This library defines a set of compiler, architecture, operating system, library, and other version numbers from the information it can gather of C, C++, Objective C, and Objective C++ predefined macros or those defined in generally available headers. The idea for this library grew out of a proposal to extend the Boost Config library to provide more, and consistent, information than the feature definitions it supports. What follows is an edited version of that brief proposal.
>
> ...
>
> - `BOOST_ARCH_` for system/CPU architecture one is compiling for.
> - `BOOST_COMP_` for the compiler one is using.
> - `BOOST_LANG_` for language standards one is compiling against.
> - `BOOST_LIB_C_` and `BOOST_LIB_STD_` for the C and C++ standard library in use.
> - `BOOST_OS_` for the operating system we are compiling to.
> - `BOOST_PLAT_` for platforms on top of operating system or compilers.
> - `BOOST_ENDIAN_` for endianness of the os and architecture combination.
> - `BOOST_HW_` for hardware specific features.
> - `BOOST_HW_SIMD` for SIMD (Single Instruction Multiple Data) detection.

You can use `BOOST_OS_*` and `BOOST_PLAT_*` for your purpose. For example

```
#include <boost/predef.h>
// or just include the necessary header
// #include <boost/predef/os.h>

#if   BOOST_OS_WINDOWS
#elif BOOST_OS_ANDROID
#elif BOOST_OS_LINUX
#elif BOOST_OS_BSD
#elif BOOST_OS_AIX
#elif BOOST_OS_HAIKU
...
#endif
```

The full list can be found in [`BOOST_OS` operating system macros](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/predef/doc/index.html#_boost_os_operating_system_macros) and [`BOOST_PLAT` platform macros](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/predef/doc/index.html#_boost_plat_platform_macros). `BOOST_HW_` can also be used to detect the hardware platform

[Demo on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIMxqkrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIAzKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/oGp6Y4CoeFRLLHxXEl2mA6ZQgRMxATZPn4Btpj2RQwNTQQlkTFxibaNza25HQrjA2FD5SNVAJS2qF7EyOwc5glhyN5YANQmCW7RqGkEAPTJxJhYVAB0CKfYJhoAgtfXRyRH2i8MyO%2B0OmCOBAQ4PCWwUCiaAE8jlCmFhiB9vr9dqCvMdTudLjNbvdHtc0i83hiMWECEdgJgCAB5IQQZZUgDsVi%2B2KoRwsjOZABUAPrM4UAdQAkhEACKM8VCDFHZUq5X3AgbBhHLhmU5cz67Lp4Xn8oWioTC4LSuQADSVqpV6s1RzMCT1VNdRpNAqEIrFFiEMvtDqOTuIWoSknd3M9tGNfJ9fotAFlPm5mcGHWGtZIAKzRg2xpSZ1XZo65gBsBcNDHwVA5Qa%2BHFWtE4ud4fg4WlIqE4bms1iOCnWm3Bux4pAImmbqwA1iBI09JGYuABOSQVySSDSu3NSfScSQd6c9zi8BQgQJTrvN0hwWAwRAoVAsZJ0OLkShoV/v%2BIAN2QZJkmFP812FBIzGFVRNz4OgCDiC8IGiE9ojCRFOAnb82EERkGFoBETywFhDGAcQb1IfB7jqP9MAvcjMFUWovHgjDeBpLoTzjaJiERDwsBPAhiDwFhWNWKgDGABQADU8EwAB3RlkkYViZEEEQxHYfd%2BEERQVHUcjdC4fQSJQAdLH0PBogvWBmDYEALiuUgaP/QDZ2AZZVlQZIejo65GS4I5rnFI8UkMSJWHYcUwnQVA5IUTpukyFxa0mPwKzMIJa0GMoKhAaQCgyARUpAdKUjSQqGGy4Z4mkGo6gEPoJk8NoSoyuqekauZSmqvKxn6YrSpmfoqsWGrVmHDYtj0QTMG2HgWzbY9yN7KLa1i%2BLry0VYICQb833oMgKAgPbfxAFg8GSBRK0kLpYNoeDiEQ5DyNQ5hiAI7heCwxgmTwj7uyIkiyIBvAqMcGi6O7BimJY8j2NbciuJ496%2BO2btBOE0S%2BAk6TZIUpTOwnbThFEcQtNkXS1BPXQK2MoxTMsawLKs%2BAIFs9gHJmJyRm4dlVxnHtvMyOiAFp/KOEXxTEWgJfFBjBKYXhkjCiIIpAEovFUBLah6ZL3Ga3I80y9ARtypICp6YqjYtzJTZGaouh1%2BpZit3Ntfq3pZjt%2BJqhdg2/CNobmm9hdxpHKajJmubbwR9tSE7btew1rXNoFlE0UoOc8q4JcuHSgAOStcwCPmzDdhGQpE3NAgT3hew4c9punbbHx258fwOz9jpffaRiaFg/3zkWDhIrguA0IyaHuhDKGe7tXvQz7SG%2BnC/sIzBiKMYHeEop2IZPaHkGY6PyEEDjEcs5GEVRgShJEz6xJxmT5MU5Sl%2BJ9SyekYnKf07tdGkAYemphGbmS4tZKA7N7KEgINzeIvN%2BYeUFj5TgYszCy2lrLeWPEJbjHpLSVQ%2BcKzCk3CLJgQF6Ai3QE0OSYQpDDyAcAJWKs1bEWQMyd2usICuGKkZEI8wcpLDKoUTIvDhEVRDkZdqzt%2Br%2Bz0NIhqXsBE9SkX7HIfhVHDWUaNCQYdJqaUnPcaOC0OBx1rqeNhHDU7bV2j3X8XcToHRAOgbQwBgDJHZB0KeD0nooTQu9FSK9fr4XXpvUiaMd6gz3rRA%2BjEj6wwnPDTil9eIYAiYYzGD9sZMEks/fGb8iayE/ppb%2BFMlBUwMiAVcdNjBmRsOA1mUDOawOchhPmAsvIoI4GgjBtAZaS2wYrUKpQ1ZyiEJwpK3CUpyL4VlbRuUjI2yKjM8RPRJETMUbI9R8jHYe06usoOLQVmHMkXo0c00jFY1jktROIAxmTmbqsdOIxWQHg4JXEA1d44nnro3K8jzSDzgrLmJ4uZ2T5w0LmBIuZcyrnZJuQubyEg3LrmeB5N4kEIzMCi08Dd0VbVWM5dIzhJBAA)

See also [demo on BOOST_ARCH](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIADspAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcYl2mA4ZQgRMxARZPn4BldUCtfUERRHRsQm2dQ1NOa1D3aG9pf3xAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMocjeWADUJutuUaipBAD0ScSYWFQAdAgH2CYaAIJnZ7sku9peCgS7Wx2mF2BAQwLCKwUCnqAE9dmCmFhiApnm8PhtAV49gcjic/hcrjczvVkAhCFUCEtMPdHqj3vszJsGNsscCccdTgTrpgqGdUKDYjT1k9XqjQv9gJgCC9lggILNUSZ4lZRYy8FRdhYAPJaoQAFQA%2Bi8AEpuAASBoAGgAOABsqN2joZmw12t1hpN5qtdoNtskDqdgcDV0pxAYuy4XAOKpegY2mFo6s1Ov1RtNFpttoN6zMAaDQZDS3DXFz6xjccZCaUefzTsLYYj612ACpk%2B6016AOpa40AEQNFgAknqhNHdvTlMRUFEmFFaHDVHaALRce2vCvrVzqxWVxOulMe9NpgCyNYx%2B/bnotJuP%2B2FB17bdTADVsMahIOteEDeE5MeLG%2BEDWqQuwaCBGgKuutbnk%2Bh5dj2/ZDiOd69g%2Bux%2BjWta7PW4ZmFGZbjh8N4AG7WtYuwvCSCAYVB%2BbxnusEdha3Z9gOw5CChaE5phtY4bsZilhYhEUcax6keRlGytxtFBvR1YyVhfGMi2jFXgaLGIexY70nIYSqEkFLXDxjrxgw%2BBUGeu5Jm6qZqTed5POsj42Yar7vp%2B36/v%2BgGJKB4GQbGWF1lKRb8f6BH0iR8S7BAN45gFG4JtZB5MSeDloS5BpuR%2BX4/n%2BAHGhAtrgf5xkFiFDZmAArNpRGicRtoxXFZgJU6cmYGVwYVbh9oRXVYlVZ8xCfLQSKWZuZnbqqm4MZlanHoOyijjJMFzUeGlschD5oTRgVBdh3W7Os%2BFCfSC1LbtiW0PJe1BXx3F9bs51CNJt2meZO4zcll5HsoyhuL6/oKbxh2SCdn1JRetm/f9nXBaG4aSIJEPXR1wP5nxS5rfBrFIaOj26QA1gwqAAO7hgwS5RIQuxURDk0WaK8Soa8HDzLQnBVbwfgcFopCoJwbjWORCiLMsbKMjwpAEJobPzIT/jxLc6waGYYO2vEeEaAAnPEObrPonCSNzsv85wvAKCAYEy7zbOkHAsAwIgKCoCwSR0LE5CUGgbse3EwAllwfB0AQsSWxAUSm9TzDEDCnBSz7bCCFqDDzqbWAsIYwDiLbpD4Fc1TEZglu55gqhVF4ofx7w4oJqbiZRMQsIeFgpsEMQeAsNX8xUAYwAKM%2BeCYKTWoGTzUv8IIIhiOwUgyIIigqOoue6AEBhGCgwuWPoeBRJbsDMGwIAcn8pBF3E3DxNrcv80kjgCCXS5alwuxLp2Yi0K/nZl%2B3TC8EkhgIisHYIuW0S4/S2ATBSDILgzIjD8CWQIZkeglDKCAA2KQ0j30yJ4ZoEgAiYIKAwFBfQ4gGzaNgzowxcE5EQRQmo4wSHTDIYMLo8D8GsIaEwtB6x5iiyWCsPQ7dMCrB4OzTmJtc4C1AeA6QNstDzAgEgH27t6BkAoBAFRfsUDr2AAaduXgGCE2DrQUOyJKCR1ztHWE1dSCJ0YAQFOadc4ZyzjnPm%2BdoFFxLnzMuFcq7cBroIOuucG5N1ji3VYfN26d27nwPuA8h4jzHrYyewhRDiDnmkxeahTa6ANrozelhrA7z3vACAh92AnwIGffol9r6zHmKgO%2BGRH5ajMK/FgOYv4fy/j/Ju/9AHhGASAGROZIH2GwbA9wNCEEBGCJMVB/QMH5GwewxBhDsHcOWRM6BHRxjrNaFA9oDAqETGKKQ9BnDGizI4X8Lo2yyF8LFoIoOwjRF2w5hwLmpAeZ82kcucZ8i7ZKJdr7NRXtNGu1Uf0eoLBSJLm2FnSMGgg40FMWHCxUdQg2MCXY12SdHGpzji4zAmcjDuN4J4wuxdTZ%2BOQJXD55BglfL5mE5uGAom8BiV3QJPcEmD2HqPRgqTZDT0ydIbJShckrxANIQpphinbwbvvKAlTj54hqefeOV8b7NOwW0jpb9elv36X/ZIQyRlwoRRA%2BhzgICuEOUg9AjyrmbIyE691hRFmXPIccyhBzbl0P9Qwh5PrmFXPudQ7Iczrmut4QsARs9pZXA%2BeI75kj/kgGtdaWR0tZaKOUdCv2kKtFqOzcQFggcwLorMeHSxfNrGx1sfY5OxL05krcVyvOeAC6OG8XS8uDKAlS1rqy3g7KImcrbh3XlYj4lMH7oK5JIq8VpPFbPSVsgcnLz5robW%2Bgs5FKsMq3eqqKkjOqbUi%2BXBdWNNvgazgT8jXv1oJ/U1qhf6DOKFaytxEKghvtY6oNzrXVBy9TgmNegINgd2Scs56y4MBrDRciNQco03Kg%2Bhxh4a0FcGeUmoRqa4lfJ%2BX83gAtrWJGBYWsFML1He2LeWuFCAqDACqpKkOmKI7YpjiShOBKHFOJJR4ztFLu3Uv7bS0uQ7GW2LHfXXe4SYSRJnbEvlC6l1JOFePXg66MmbvnvIaVu6dASCDgqreNgVXlPVVe7V9S9UtIfk%2B9pPS319M/U3TpdMnLWttN%2BoBR9/NIZgQ6uBQaD0LNQzwvIWCPWRbi0Q%2BNoX9lsMS3a05OGYs7Iw%2Bsg9GH40EfFkRkRJGJG/NNpRv9xUaP2yLeCz2Giy2wsrcASQHGTF1qxVYnFza8WtqJc40T5Ls4Sd7V46TvjZMjqCaHcdpTlOqdzjyuJvdF2JKFSktdYqDMSC3QvEzeSJBgUs0q6zZ7bOXs1denVDSmnOYYIa9z77v5eaYD52UD5rU/IAT%2B4Lf6qqpb8OFmZWGovINwzsiD%2BWktbKhywzLCGMuAayyhqYsW8sZeyxj5ZxXXkprKxp0jmaKMVvhUDmj8wERIkoPLOVXBbjqzMNaKqtoqpmA0FfaqhsODG1IF3KqYFyNmw4BbXIdWHbOxawxqFjW4hJCSMgP09BgAHtrdxhtvAm38d4IN4THbRuUp7X2vAA6ZP%2BKZQp0JSmOWtxW7OtbArtPbYnrtme%2B2jM7uO4kM7J6LtlIPtd04t3HP3v1a01zL9jUeY/V%2Bi1/32B/TcLa1H0zEPRdx3EcDqyEtYbhxkWDSPA35%2BL%2BjpZ2frmIcKwjiQ%2BPk3vPKxmyrUiQDJ4gZLhr9HS1Mf6Ir5AAcSw1q4%2BYnjvW%2BMtsE224bVKxNjfThNmlPjeD0rk3i63bLbdTvt9Ex3Gn1taa26ut3U89tZO3Ud2VwE/clJs0Ho%2B9m6m3vuw%2ByPHAn7R9fa9s1gXhlH2T%2BMpluniBpnhXtBrngIIhjBrXuhqjsjqXnATjmAdhulqXkgZcvhomiVm8sRsThViLgLAAQEJ3nRiWs1r3nECwHgEkAoGzpIAmF1prrxrigJiwISgbqSkbuNqbubtNpbqbBvhOlviptOg7upvOgfptiurpkZhup7lKkvMdsVDfqeoHmqsHqfA5s/k5o%2Bu/s/C9p5vHn9kFuwM9KnpMmFsBvnqARgQXpASBtATlpXmXtGngrARYWllwjAVXiBjXk4XXlgQTo3ngc3gQSAGYXIgWvVqQRCuQfLiAFQTQZGJzowaPlrqQDrpPmwUJu2pwV2gvjwVNivjNt2oIYtnbt2qtvvs7kfjIfph7ufodoobKkDioQHuenZjdloXeg9roR/gYXHgMgniYeEYtC9Ech4SDlYXgh1qBrXisvFvYVBrMY4VnpGogagTMUDi4ecmseQiXlsXGvMfXqVmmrzmRlVqMUtEClEaCjLj3vEcRMgIrgaMRFwNrNmGYAaKoBAhrmkcwf1qwewbkSNvkS4ovlJsvoECUfJiyopo3BUWpnOnbJIcujpqKqfg0QdsZs0XunoG0aUqqr0ZHmcM/MMX/iAuYXslMRFtYZDv4TnosZBm4XYcQt4TsdXhsV4QyT4WgeXhgScTgUTvOiTi3lmj8ZEbbLRvcXEfRiAMQA1JIEuMAMgMgNrJIMPhiv8ePiwXrlPkNiJrPlwQUZNlCavrNsyvNvCUtqIbvuISiTUdIRiekliV7pfniYggSXfuoQ/l0U/j0a/i5noZ/iam9kYZakfMaIOEIG4EuM%2BMDsAVhvMvSXsayZ6hAWyf4X6pMfAW4RMdSWcilljkmUcVmYKYTmcaKWEVGTGXGfmlKdTpgIiP0PKLzvzoLsLpcWLrYFbPWQovTprLcLaLrFVNaDmPENaNrKrLaNfpwOsKTqLtygWummYAuQLN2VTtemkM4JIEAA%3D%3D)